# Disable click on RecyclerView inside a SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I implemented a `SwipeRefreshLayout` using a `RecyclerView` and I need that my adapter items are disabled during the `OnRefreshListener`.

I tried the following approach, but the click occurs normally:

```
mRecyclerView.setEnabled(false);
mRecyclerView.setClickable(false);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use logic we had with `ListAdapter`. This will disable adapter items, instead their parent.

```
public interface RecyclerViewItemEnabler{
  public boolean isAllItemsEnabled();
  public boolean getItemEnabled(int position);
}
```

And implementation should look like this:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements RecyclerViewItemEnabler{

    @Override
    public void onViewAttachedToWindow(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);
        holder.itemView.setEnabled(isAllItemsEnabled());
        //or do this in onBindViewHolder()
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAllItemsEnabled(){ return mAllEnabled; }

    @Override
    public boolean getItemEnabled(int position){
       return true;
    }
    public void setAllItemsEnabled(boolean enable){
      mAllEnabled = enable;
      notifyItemRangeChanged(0, getItemCount());
    }

}
```

Usage:
`mRecylerAdapter.setAllItemsEnabled(!mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing());`

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work for me. Not only can I click on every item but all items also blink simultaneously on click. I implemented this exact code, seems straight forward but...