# Make Recycler View Inactive

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view I'm using with a GridLayoutManager.  When the user clicks on an item of view, a view is animatated with scale animation to display further details of the adapter item.  I have a button to reverse this animation and remove the details off screen.

The problem is when the details view is displayed the user can still click on the recycler view and animate a different view.  Can any tell me how to disable the recycler view?

I've tried `rc_view.setEnabled(false);`
           `rc_view.setClickable(false);`

and I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27927830/disable-click-on-recyclerview-inside-a-swiperefreshlayout) and none of them has disabled the recycler view.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Might sound stupid, but same thing happened to me on my menu (when clicking on open spaces the click events were passed to the recycler). This was fixed by adding "clickable='true'" on the top view so it doesn't pass the click event to the recyclerview. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: excellent!  will you put that in an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: There you go. Glad I could help.

Comment: could you please elaborate this more ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Might sound stupid, but same thing happened to me on my menu (when clicking on open spaces the click events were passed to the recycler).

This was fixed by adding "clickable='true'" on the top view so it doesn't pass the click event to the recyclerview.

Let me know if this helps

Answer (score 2):

Use `recyclerView.setClickable(true)`

Comment: Post already answered.  Your answer is a duplicate of the accepted answer