# How to make RecyclerView's items non clickable?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I tried the following code:

```
view.setEnabled(false);
myReqRecyclerView.setEnabled(false);
```

The first line disables the current view which is clicked. After one click, I want to set all items non clickable so that double click should not happen.
It seems that the second line is not working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27977229/1099716

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

**First Simple option**

but quite bad actually would by to use System time :

```
 long mLastClickTime = 0;

    youradapter.setOnItemClickListener(new youradapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position) {

            if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 1000) {
                return;
            }
            mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

            ....//your code


        }
    });
```

but for a clean programming I would recommend doing this :

**A bit trickier but as simple**

In your Adapter introduce a boolean variable, please pay attention to the viewHolder() and onBindViewHolder() methods :

```
private boolean clickable = true;


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    if (!clickable){
        viewHolder.cardView.setClickable(false);
    } else {
        viewHolder.cardView.setClickable(true);
    }

    //....
}

public void setClickable(boolean clickable) {
    this.clickable = clickable;
    myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    CardView cardView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView, final myViewHolder.OnItemClickListener listener){
        super(itemView);
        //..

        cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);

        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        listener.onItemClick(position);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and use myadapter.setClickable(state) as you wish

like this :

```
    youradapter.setOnItemClickListener(new youradapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position) {

            myadapter.setClickable(false);

            ....//your code


        }
    });
```

and maybe in your onResume() :

```
 myadapter.setClickable(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent touch for viewGroup children by overriding the method below and return true;

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try view.setClickable(false);  on the view which you dont want to be clickable

Comment: I want to complete recycler view non clickable.and view.setClickable(false); not working for this.

Comment: @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, final int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.nfn_row_item, viewGroup, false);view.setClickable(false); 
        return new CustomViewHolder(view);
    }

Comment: I want just one option to make all items non clickable, but you suggest set clickable false for all items

Answer (score 0):

In your recyclerView adapter you will be having a method like this:

```
@Override
public YourViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View partnerTypeView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);
    return new YourViewHolder(partnerTypeView);
}
```

Add the following line to it:

```
    @Override
    public YourViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View partnerTypeView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);
        partnerTypeView.setClickable(false);//This is line that make row non clickable
        return new YourViewHolder(partnerTypeView);
    }
```

Comment below if this doesn't work

Comment: Thanks for reply, It will disable all the items but I simply want that when we click on one item just after that whole recyclerview should be disable.

Answer (score 0):

Let the list items take the `enabled` parameter from the parent in adapter's code:

```
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    view.setEnabled(parent.isEnabled());
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}
```

Then all you have to do is set the value for the list itself and set the adapter again:

```
recyclerView.setEnabled(false);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```