# RecyclerView item selected and how to disable Touch events

Tags: android, touch, android-recyclerview, adapter

There are all kinds of materials on how to do a simple `RecyclerView` click event handler but I can't find help with this basic desired functionality. I want to be able to `long tap` on an item so that it becomes selected (see how I change elevation and color to make it appear selected). Then, if in my `Fragment` I'd like to remove one item from the `RecyclerView` based on a `Toolbar` delete button clicked for example, how would I do that if Google suggest that we shouldn't be keeping an instance of the position from the adapter outside of the class.

I implemented a `BottomSheet` from the 23.2.0 support library, it appears above my `RecyclerView` but clicks go through and it's like I'm controlling the RecyclerView itself but instead I also have a `BottomSheet` on top. How can I really 'disable' it?

**I've tried**: using an [interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27927830/disable-click-on-recyclerview-inside-a-swiperefreshlayout), setting `clickable=true` to top layout View.

My `RecyclerAdapter`:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.EventViewHolder> {
private List<Event> eventsList;
private int selected_position = -1;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;



Typeface font;
Typeface fontBold;

public RecyclerAdapter(List<Event> eventsList, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    this.eventsList = eventsList;
    this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
}

@Override
public RecyclerAdapter.EventViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.
            from(parent.getContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.events_cardview, parent, false);

    font = Typeface.createFromAsset(itemView.getContext().getAssets(), "ubuntu-l.ttf");
    fontBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(itemView.getContext().getAssets(), "ubuntu-b.ttf");

    return new EventViewHolder(itemView);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerAdapter.EventViewHolder eventViewHolder,final int position) {


    if(selected_position == position){
        // Here I am just highlighting the background
        eventViewHolder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MyApplication.getAppContext(), R.color.tealfifty));
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            eventViewHolder.itemView.setElevation(10f);
            eventViewHolder.itemView.setTranslationZ(10f);
        }
    }else{
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            eventViewHolder.itemView.setElevation(2f);
            eventViewHolder.itemView.setTranslationZ(2f);
        }
        eventViewHolder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MyApplication.getAppContext(), R.color.white));
    }

    eventViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager lm = recyclerView.getLayoutManager();

            // Updating old as well as new positions
            notifyItemChanged(selected_position);
            selected_position = position;
            notifyItemChanged(selected_position);
            lm.scrollToPosition(selected_position);
        }
    });

    Event event = eventsList.get(position);
    eventViewHolder.itemView.setTag(R.integer.EVENT_OBJECT_TAG, event);
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }
    });
```

I return in `onInterceptTouchEvent` true, for no effect after touch item recycler view.