# How can I disable click or touch event in recyclerview when swiperefresh.isRefreshing()

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

**Need Help**

I'm trying to block the touch or click event on `CardView` when `swiperefresh.isrefreshing()` is active and after refreshing is done again I can click on cards.

I want it to work like Progress Bar when the progressBar is active we can `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(boolean)` and when `ProgressBar` done its work again click events are active. Thanks!

Comment: Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27977229/8089770

Comment: it is not duplicate question Actually I tried to find out the answer but I'm not able find the correct answer that's why I thought ask the you guys needs to think before giving duplicate question. thanks for the help.

Comment: that is not working.

Answer (score -1):

```
RecyclerView.setLayoutFrozen(boolean frozen);
```

Enable or disable layout and scroll.

Comment: I tried with this but not working

Comment: recyclerView.setEnabled(false);   try it